# Javascript to check for form data does not work

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have the following code to check for form data and I can't figure out why its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkStuff() {
                // By default, we plan to submit the form.
                var formOkay = 1;

                // Check to see if field_1 has a value.  If not, we note that by changing our variable.
                if(document.getElementById('requestorfirstname').value == '')
                    formOkay = 0;

                // Let the user know something is wrong somehow.  An alert is easiest.
                alert('Requestor Name Required!');

                // If you return true the form will submit.  If you return false it will not.
                if(formOkay == 1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Now here is the html form piece its checking onsubmit.

```
<input type="text" name="requestorfirstname" />
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById` looks for elements by ID. Your field doesn't have an ID, it has a NAME.

Comment: That was it!  After I fixed it the form still completed, what do I need to change to go back to the form instead of continuing?  Thanks

Comment: It all depends on how you are calling this function.

Comment: I'm calling it onsubmit when the button is pressed.

Comment: Use a regular button. Use onclick to call your function, then submit the form if it passes validation.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` selects an element by `id`, not by `name`.

Some ways to solve the problem:

- Add `id="requestorfirstname"` to the input element.
- Use [`document.getElementsByName('requestorfirstname')[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName). `getElementsByName` returns a list, hence `[0]`.
- Use the [`document.querySelector('[name="requestorfirstname"]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) method.
- Get a reference to the form, and access the element using the `.elements` collection.
  For example, if your page has only one form:

  ```
  document.forms[0].elements['requestorfirstname']
  ```

Answer (score 2):

A `name` attribute on an HTML element is NOT the same as an `id`. You have no id on your input field, so there's no way for `getElementById` to find it. Change the element to:

```
<input type="text" name="requestorfirstname" id="requestorfirstname" />
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - add this
```